# Simple code for playing music in pygame doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame, playback, mixer

So I've looked a lot how to play a sound in `pygame`. The code underneath is how far I got. But when I run it there is no error code but also , nothing actually happens. Can somebody please tell me what to change or what code actually works? I've researched a lot but nothing helped.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('file')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

A better way to wait for the end would be to check get_busy periodically and exit when it returns false.

Answer (score 3):

`mixer.music.play()` is an asynchronous function, so it will start playing music and let the program continue running.

So your program starts a music and then quits immediately.

Applications made with *pygame* are expected to run in an event loop, so it is logical that the function is asynchronous.

The solution is to implement an event loop (look at some tutorials).

There is also a workaround: add a `pygame.event.wait()` call after `...play()`